# SQl Query in VBA Access: Workaround for quotation mark contained in object name

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am using VBA in Microsoft Access and trying to define a recordset using the following SQL query in my VBA code.

```
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT food, compound FROM Composition_data", dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)
Set rs6 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [ID] FROM Compounds WHERE Compounds.Name = """ & rs1("compound") & """", dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)
```

I am having trouble with defining `rs6`. My issue is not the query itself, but with `rs1("compound")`. The compound names unfortunately contain quotation marks which disrupt the query statement in VBA. This derives from chemical nomenclature and cannot be changed.

Any ideas how to workaround this? I've tried both () and [] brackets in various constellations, but they do not override the " contained in the compound name.

Comment: How many quotation marks are there in a compound? Is the number and position of the quotation marks always the same?

Comment: I believe there are up to 2 quotation marks (") in the name and the position of the quotation marks can differ from row to row. For example: Cyanidin 3-O-(6''-malonyl-3''-glucosyl-glucoside)

Comment: The names can also contain apostrophes ('), round brackets, square brackets, and dashes. However these haven't caused any trouble so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to duplicate the quotation marks ("escape" them in VB syntax):

```
Set rs6 = db.OpenRecordset( _
    "SELECT [ID] FROM Compounds WHERE Compounds.Name = """ & _
    REPLACE(rs1("compound"),"""","""""") & _
    """", dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly _
)
```

Or use a parametrized query (? syntax in Access VBA), which is the preferred solution to be *safe for scripting*, especially when `compound` can contain user-input data.

Comment: why not use `& Chr(34)` instead ? not easier on the why ? instead of couting the `"` ?

Comment: granted that VBA's escaping syntax is ugly, we would need two of those in the third argument to `REPLACE`, so I preferred inline escaping to multiple concats.